# How do I interpret price elasticity when using state specific dummies and price, dummy interaction

Tags: econometrics, linear-model, categorical-encoding, elasticity

I have price volume data for 3 states for which I want to calculate price elasticity for each state.
The model has the following setup:

$$
\ln(Y)=A_1+ A_2\ln(P) +A_3D_1 +A_4D_2+ A_5\ln(P)D_1 +A_6\ln(P)D_2
$$
where:

- $A_2,\ldots,A_6$ are coefficients
- $A_1$ is the intercept
- $D_1$ is the dummy for state 1
- $D_2$ is the dummy for state 2
- $P$ is price, taken log
- $Y$ is quantity, taken log

The elasticity for state 3 would be $A_2$.

1. What would be the elasticity for state 1, would it be $A_5$ or $A_2+A_5$?
2. How do I interpret $A_2$ and $A_5$ in words?

Answer (score 0):

The sum is the right one to use. You can derive that by taking the derivative with respect to $P$ and rearranging that until you only have the coefficients on the right.

The interpretation of the sum is the same as any elasticity: it is the percent change in quantity demanded associated with a 1% increase in price for that state.

This interpretation assumes that prices are not endogenous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if I am understanding it right, the elasticity interpretation for state 1 is independent from the reference state (state 3)?

Comment: State 3 elasticity is just A2. State 1 is A2+A5, and State 2 is A2+A6. They are not independent since the last two include the first one. If you alter the baseline state, you should still get the same answer, so it does not matter which one gets dropped.

Comment: @Sim Did that clear things up?